# Varias Base de Datos Identity MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, autenticación, identity

Quiero hacer que **ApplicationSignInManager** y **ApplicationUserManager** cambien de base de datos dinamicamente. Ya que por defecto toma la cadena de conexion que tiene la app al iniciar.

### Startup:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
//Mas código...
}
```

Esto hace que al usar **ApplicationSignInManager** y **ApplicationUserManager** tengan por defecto la base de datos de inicio. Pero necesito variar eso para que pueda elegir a través de código cual base de datos usaran, ya que necesito por ejemplo registrar usuarios en diferentes base de datos además de iniciar sesión.

Estuve probando algo como esto:

```
using (var adb = new ApplicationDbContext(companyName))
{
   var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
   var users = adb.Users.ToList();
   var users2 = userManager.Users.ToList();
}
```

Como ven trate de tener una instancia nueva de User Manager pero esta tomando el contexto owin para obtenerlo lo que hace que obtenga los que se crearon en el **Startup** es decir que no puedo cambiar la base de datos pero el contexto de EntityFramework si cambia.

Quiero hacer que la aplicacion sea de tenencia multiple con identity de manera que segun envie un parámetro al controlador tome un conection string y este se aplique a Entity Framework y Identity.

Comment: ¿Quiéres usar varias bases de datos que tienen diferente información, o la misma base de datos pero de diferente ambiente como dev, release, producción, etc?

Comment: En realidad diferentes base de datos con la misma estructura pero diferentes datos

Answer (score 1):

Debido a tus comentarios y al ejemplo que expones, creo que intentas acceder a la misma base de datos, pero en diferente ambiente, misma estructura y diferentes datos.

Lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es crear tres entradas en tu archivo de configuración, una para saber el ambiente y las otras dos con la cadena de conexión, el valor de la cadena de conexión dependerá del resultado del operador ternario.

En el archivo web.config, crearás las llaves dentro de sección `appSettings`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="development" />
    <add key="ConnectionStringDev" value="Cadena de conexión de desarrollo" />
    <add key="ConnectionStringProd" value="Cadena de conexión de producción" />
</appSettings>
```

En la clase donde desees crear el contexto de base de datos:

```
string environment = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];    

using (var adb = new ApplicationDbContext(environment == "development" ? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringDev"] : System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringProd"]))
{
    var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var users = adb.Users.ToList();
    var users2 = userManager.Users.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero en realidad lo que quiero hacer es multitendency con identity. Cambiare algunas cosas para no dirigir la atención a este punto.

Comment: La palabra correcta es `multi-tenancy`